# Ruby - Execution expired

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a ruby code like this:

```
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read.strip)
rescue Exception => ex
  log.error "Error: #{ex}"
end
```

And I am getting log as:

```
ERROR -- : Error: execution expired
```

I want block re-execute until it success.

How can I do it?

Comment: First of all try to open the url separetly from passing it into nokogiri, as this might enable easier bugfixing

Comment: You mean this?:
 `doc = open(url).read.strip
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)`

Comment: No I mean `data = open(url).read.strip` then on the next line `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data)`

Comment: And if you really want to go back to the `begin` from the `rescue`, use `retry` (but watch out for infinite loops).

Comment: ok. the same I tried to ask you. but I forgot to format the `code` :)

Comment: Could you give the URL, so we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment a little bit. You can use `retry` to go back to the `begin`:

```
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read.strip)
rescue Exception => ex
  log.error "Error: #{ex}"
  retry
end
```

That will keep trying (and logging errors) until it works or you manually kill it. That's probably not what you want though as one little mistake will send you into an infinite loop. An easy way around that is to let it try for, say, 10 times and then give up:

```
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10

doc = nil
begin
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read.strip)
rescue Exception => ex
  log.error "Error: #{ex}"
  attempts = attempts + 1
  retry if(attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS)
end

if(doc.nil?)
  # Do something about the persistent error
  # so that you don't try to access a nil
  # doc later on.
end
```

Something like this will try a few times and then give up. You could also put a [`sleep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) call before the `retry` if you want to wait a bit before the next attempt or investigate the exception (possibly with multiple `rescue` blocks) to choose if you should give up immediately, wait and retry, or retry immediately.