# retry in Ruby can not be performed

Tags: ruby

```
for i in 1..5
   retry if  i > 2
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

When I ran the code above, I got an error message saying **Invalid retry**

The version of Ruby I was using is 1.9.3. Would anyone know what went wrong with the code?

Comment: That's an infinite loop! Don't do it :)

Comment: I believe that in recent versions of Ruby `retry` can only be used only in `rescue` clauses.

Comment: [Ruby's `retry` is part of its exception handling system](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6340839/479863), there's no `begin`...`end` or `rescue` in your code so there's nothing to retry (and no exceptions for that matter). What are you expecting `retry` to do?

Comment: @muistooshort, I've seen that very code snippet (verbatim) in older Ruby docs, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), for example, along with its use in a `rescue` clause.

Comment: @Cary So we're having the good old ancient and out of date tutorial problem then? Blarg.

Comment: @muistooshort when did this change?

Comment: @jamesw No idea, I'm not familiar with using `retry` in a loop like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Ruby 1.9 onwards retry needs to be in a rescue clause and will only work when in a rescue clause